# Express the cokernel of a linear map as a sum of cyclic groups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Let $T=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3 \\ 5&4&2\\1&2&3\\2&1&4
> \end{pmatrix}$. What is the cokernel of $T$ as a sum of cyclic groups?

From my calculation, the Smith Normal Form of $T$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&9\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$. So the cokernel of $T$ is, by definition, $\mathbb{Z}^4/\mathbb{Z} \oplus3\mathbb{Z}\oplus9\mathbb{Z}$. My question is, how do I write this as a sum of cyclic groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the image of $T$ is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus3\mathbb{Z}\oplus9\mathbb{Z}\oplus\{0\}$, so $$\operatorname{Coker}T=\mathbb{Z}^4/\mathbb{Z} \oplus3\mathbb{Z}\oplus9\mathbb{Z}\oplus\{0\}\simeq\mathbb Z/\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/\{0\}\simeq\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/9\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z.$$